# Referencing an external editable CSV file in a spatialite base

Tags: qgis, csv, attribute-joins, excel, spreadsheet

I would like to join a CSV file attributes to multiple spatialite layers, but I would like to be able to edit the csv externally (export it from a different project on Excel or Numbers every time I make a change).

I've done this with SHP layers and it worked fine, as long as I re-opened the project to refresh the join.

I'm getting started with Spatialite layers instead of SHP mostly because I want the ability to create dynamic views with simple queries.
I'm wondering if it's possible to keep such link with a csv that is stored outside of the database, or if I will have to ditch Excel/Numbers altogether and only work from within the DB. I would like to keep these tools for many other functions that are not spatial-related, and for which I'm a lot more proficient than SQL/DB (zero experience).